# Simple, local taggable link store / bookmark application?

Tags: information-management, bookmark

I just want a very simple program which lets me enter a link, and some tags, and then later easily search on those tags (just 'pull out everything with this tag' would be good enough, but 'pull out everything with all of these tags / any of these tags' would be nice).

Everything I've found has either required me to essentially set up the database schema myself / code it myself, or been special-purpose (e.g. a CRM or a bug tracking system), or had number-of-item restrictions or poor export functionality (I expect to end up with around 100k items in this and I need to know that at least that I can get it out in .csv or similar if necessary).

I've looked at the [Self hosted, searchable bookmark application](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11066/self-hosted-searchable-bookmark-application) recommendations but I don't want to have to host something open to the web.

Google Bookmarks is *very* similar to what I want - but appears to only export in an awkward HTML format and doesn't give me the ability to search on multiple tags.

Comment: Standalone program or is a browser addon OK? Price, OS? Data must be stored in a DB? Please [edit].

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [RedNotebook](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/) - it is a journal that stores everything in plain text, with zipped backup, can export to a wide range of formats, gives you a free form to add tags but still recognises links.

- Free
- Multiplatform
- Live searches

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to store your bookmarks in a mind map using [Free Mind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/) - you can arrange your bookmarks in a collection of folded categories, browse on the categories or search for them and just expand the tags that match your search, click on the links to go to them, etc.  You can also export your mind map to a javascript or flash plug in with the same functionality.

- Free
- Local install
- Export to your devices as flash/java script
- If you export as flash/java script to a web location then you can reference it on the move
- Organize your bookmarks and search them
- Mind Maps are stored as XML so recovering all the links to a .csv file could be done with a simple grep or python script.

Screenshot of a part of the documentation in flash showing some clickable links:

[image]