# Local bookmark manager for Kubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bookmark

I am searching for a browser-independent manager for web bookmarks that I can install on my local Kubuntu (Ubuntu + KDE) machine.  It would also be great if that bookmark manager could be accessible from a web interface, so that I could potentially put it on my own server.

The program should provide hierarchical folders. I should be able to put descriptions on web links, as well as tags.

The tags should be displayed in an overview (tag cloud).

It would be nice if the tags could be put in a hierarchy as well. Then I wouldn't need a folder hierarchy anymore.

A bonus would be if the manager were able to find 404 links.

PS: [Self hosted, searchable bookmark application](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11066/self-hosted-searchable-bookmark-application) seems pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same thing, and have come across a command line solution, called [buku](https://www.maketecheasier.com/manage-browser-bookmarks-ubuntu-command-line/).  Put the database on some cloud storage, and you should be good to go!

If you want a browser addon, there's [xBroswerSync](https://www.xbrowsersync.org/) or [syncmarx](https://syncmarx.mcleodgaming.com/).

I'm not sure about tags/404's.