# Website that will let me share music I listen to?

Tags: web-apps, music

#### Books

I am a passionate reader. I keep track of books I read through goodreads.com, a web app that is basically meant to be your library on the web. That has a lot of advantages, the main of which is, for me, that it is shareable.

When someone asks ‘what do you like to read?’ I simply give them my goodreads URL, that shows all the books I own and have read. [Here an example with a random user](https://www.goodreads.com/eliza). I’m not sharing *the books*, you can’t read them, I’m just showing you what I enjoy reading.

#### Music

I am looking for the exact same service for music. I listen to music through iTunes, so I have a bunch of artists, each one with a bunch of albums and songs.

When someone asks ‘what music do you listen to?’ I’d like to have an URL/profile somewhere where these artists and albums are listed. I don’t want to share the actual songs, a list of what I listen to is enough.

Is there a similar service, a goodreads for music?

#### Example of what I am not looking for

There are web apps offering a similar functionality for *playlists* (e.g. Spotify public playlists), but it’s a fairly different thing. I have thousands of songs. The URL should give an overview of my own library (artists & albums, possibly indicating how much I liked them), not random songs from it.

#### Example of what I am looking for

It’s not the best that I can imagine, but Facebook has a decent functionality for this. In your info page, there are different sections for Music, Video, Books. And they collect Facebook pages that you liked. Sadly,

- It sucks a bit, in that everything music related that you liked ends up there, and there’s no hierarchy. Also, you have to choose whether to stop at the ‘artist’ level or the ‘album’ level, or mix the two...
- You don’t have a public facing URL for the Music section. Yes, you can pass your Facebook URL and have Music open to public, but... you know.

Comment: Hi. Did you find anything? Please let me know. A site that allows sharing/display of bookmarks may work...

Answer (score 1):

[Last.FM](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=last.fm)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last.fm):

> Last.fm is a music website founded in the United Kingdom in 2002. Using a music recommender system called "Audioscrobbler", Last.fm builds a detailed profile of each user's musical taste by recording details of the tracks the user listens to, either from Internet radio stations, or the user's computer or many portable music devices. This information is transferred ("scrobbled") to Last.fm's database either via the music player itself (including, among others Spotify, Deezer, Tidal, MusicBee, and Anghami) or via a plug-in installed into the user's music player. The data is then displayed on the user's profile page and compiled to create reference pages for individual artists.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an online bookmarks manager that enables sharing, display, classification of bookmarks for this purpose.

Some examples include:

- [Wallabag](https://www.wallabag.org) - it has a paid hosted solution, and also opensource from [github](https://github.com/wallabag/wallabag) if you want to self-host
- [TagPacker](https://tagpacker.com) - "free tool to collect, organize, and share your favorite links".

If you decide to self-hosted, a couple of other suggestions are [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11066/self-hosted-searchable-bookmark-application). The is also [buku](https://github.com/jarun/buku).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [Wakelet](https://wakelet.com/).  Wakelet gives you the ability to collect bookmarks and then organize them into collections.  Each collection can have one or more pages.  The pages allow you to import embeds from many other sites as well as music and videos.  So, if you are a Tom Petty Fan, you could have a Tome Petty collection, and for instance a page titled "Running Down A Dream" with links to the song on various platforms and even embed the YouTube video right in the page.  Plus, everything you link to or embed gits a bookmarks that you can reuse on other pages.  It's a really cool site.